How to handle exceptions globally AND show to user?
I'm building a MAUI app and have just finished adding the MetroLog library but then realized I want the user to also know about any errors happening in the application.
I found one potential solution here (registering an event handler to AppDomain.CurrentDomain.FirstChanceException):
How Do You Create A Global Error Handling for a MAUI App
But this is registered in the App class which is not a Page and can't display an alert for the user.
I moved the event handler registration to the AppShell class and now using the DisplayAlert() seems to be possible but after starting the app it crashes after cca. 10s (and only when DisplayAlert() is present in the code).
How can I correctly display the globally caught exception to the user?

You moved the exception to a class instance that may not be available when an exception is thrown. Or the OS may not like displaying multiple alerts at the same time. Leave the handler where it is and use it to raise a notification that some other part of the application subscribes to. That could be a message posted to a queue, which would allow the app to display alerts one at a time and filter what gets displayed.

Could you show some sample code for raising a notification and how to subscribe to it elsewhere in the app? And also, where in the app should it subscribe?
